# How do I handle multiple carets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I'm developing a Visual Studio Extension/VSIX package for work that involves changing the caret's position. Of course, dealing with a single caret is easy:

```
/// Get the Host of current active view
private async Task<IWpfTextViewHost> GetCurrentViewHostAsync()
{
    // First get the active view:
    var txtManager = (IVsTextManager)await ServiceProvider.GetServiceAsync(typeof(SVsTextManager));
    Assumes.Present(txtManager);
    IVsTextView vTextView = null;
    const int mustHaveFocus = 1;
    textManager.GetActiveView(mustHaveFocus, null, out vTextView);

    if (vTextView is IVsUserData userData)
    {
        // Get host
        IWpfTextViewHost viewHost;
        object holder;
        Guid guidViewHost = DefGuidList.guidWpfTextViewHost;
        userData.GetData(ref guidViewHost, out holder);
        viewHost = (IWpfTextViewHost)holder;

        return viewHost;
    }

    return null;
}

// Later:
private async void ExecCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IWpfTextViewHost host = await GetCurrentViewHostAsync();

    // Access single caret
    host.TextView.Caret.MoveTo(/* New position here */);
}
```

But let's say I use the "Insert Next Matching Caret" command to insert another caret, so I have two different carets now. Moving the caret using the above method will remove the second caret, and as far as I can tell, `IVsTextView` only has a single Caret property.

My next idea was that I'm supposed to access other cursors with other [IVsTextManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextmanager?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) interfaces in the `host`, but the closest thing I can find is its `EnumViews(IVsTextBuffer, IVsEnumTextViews)` method, which always returns some negative, non-`S_OK` value and leaves the `IVsEnumTextViews` item as `null`. A similar thing happens with the `EnumIndependentViews` method.

Am I approaching this right? How does the "Multiple Carets" thing even work? I can't find any documentation on it. Does the API even let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you have to use `ITextView2`'s (Not `ITextView`) `MultiSelectionBroker` property, which can only be accessed with TextView's `GetMultiSelectionBroker` Extension method. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.imultiselectionbroker) for more details on it.

```
private async void ExecCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ConfigureAwait(true) is just to silence warnings about adding ConfigureAwait(false)
    // "false" will cause this to not function properly. (Carets won't update).
    IWpfTextViewHost host = await GetCurrentViewHostAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);

    // Because TextView is only ITextView and not ITextView2, 
    //  we can only access the MultiSelectionBroker property with the extension method:
    IMultiSelectionBroker selectionBroker = host.TextView.GetMultiSelectionBroker();
    foreach (var selection in selectionBroker.AllSelections)
    {
        var nextPoint = GetSomePointHere(host, selection);
        selectionBroker.TryPerformActionOnSelection(
            selection,
            t => t.MoveTo(nextPoint, false, PositionAffinity.Successor),
            out Selection after
        );
    }
}
```

Don't know why, but I must have completely missed the docs for `ITextView2` when I wrote the question.

Note: The default `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI.dll` will not contain this method because it is an extension method. You can remove the dll reference from the solution and re-add the correct one (under Extensions) to fix this.